# How do I mark an Excel range NoProofing? or turn off spell checking for a range?

Tags: excel, vba

Given my fat fingers, I use speel check a lot.  Sometimes in Word or Outlook when I want to mark a section no-spell-checking-here *(these are not the words you want, move on).* I use this code:

```
Sub ns()
' Mark region as no spell check
     Selection.NoProofing = True
End Sub
```

I use similar code in Outlook.

In both cases I add the macro to the the *quick access bar* using the builtin glyph   *<<abc>>.*

In Excel I would like to mark a column in a table to avoid spell checking.  The noProofing property does not seem to exist, so the code above does not do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That setting does not exist in Excel, AFAIK. You can reverse the process and spell check only the selected range.

```
Selection.CheckSpelling SpellLang:=5129 ' That is New Zealand English
```

If you would like this property added to Excel, you could post a suggestion in http://excel.uservoice.com where people can vote for feature suggestions. Microsoft closely monitors this site and will consider new features based on the number of votes.

Comment: Thank you teylyn.  I was afraid that it was not in the Excel object model.  I checked the site that you suggested; [excel.uservoice.com](http://excel.uservoice.com).  I opened a suggestion [suggestions/17594389-add-the-vba-range-noproofing-property-to-excel](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/17594389-add-the-vba-range-noproofing-property-to-excel-li)  Others might want to add votes to the suggestion. (and thank you for the edits)